# Throwing UnsupportedDataTypeException explicitly without declaring Throws in the method signature

Tags: java, anagram

I came across a problem on HackerRank where method is written like this.

```
public static String anagram(String s , String s1){

//write ur logic

throw new UnsupportedDataTypeException("anagram(String s , String s1)");    
}
```

I can not edit anything in this method signature. Now I have written my logic below:

```
public static String anagram(String s , String s1){

        String str="";
        char []a=s.trim().toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char []b=s1.trim().toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        Arrays.sort(a);
        Arrays.sort(b);
        boolean isAnag=false;
        isAnag=Arrays.equals(a, b);

        if(isAnag){
            str= "yes";
        }
        else{
            str= "no";
        }
        return str;
        throw new UnsupportedDataTypeException("anagram(String s , String s1)");
    }
```

Now whatever I do. This UnsupportedDataTypeException is giving me compilation error, even when I added try catch block with my code but the exception is still there. I cannot use Throws keyword in the method signature because its non editable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like the `throw new UnsupportedDataTypeException("anagram(String s , String s1)");` was just an implementation stub. I believe you can just remove it, because this statement is unreachable. You can't put any code after the `return` statement, such code will be unreachable and the compilation will fail. See more about checked and unchecked exceptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation).

Comment: (Where did you find this?  The versions of the problem I found with Google didn't have that `throw` statement.)

Comment: This was on hackerRank site .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `throw new UnsupportedDataTypeException("anagram(String s , String s1)");` was just an implementation stub.

You can just remove it, because this statement is unreachable. You can't put any code after the `return` statement, such code i unreachable so the compilation will fail.

See more about checked and unchecked exceptions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation). If you need to throw an exception from your method, consider throwing a `RuntimeException` or create your own runtime exception and throw it.

Comment: I'd say it is a hint that the expected format and possible resulting exceptions should be handled. More likely expected to move it rather than remove it.

Comment: No . I cant edit anything of that format. We just have to follow that and write our code between that.